# indicator-weather doesn't work

Tags: 11.04, unity, indicator, weather

For the past couple days cannot indicator-weather on the panel?  What can I do to make it back on the panel. But I can see it in system monitor and it's sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

Find the process-id in system monitor, then run

```
ubuntu-bug PID
```

on that process.  Then if you like, paste the bug number here and someone may be able to help more.  It's working for me, for what that's worth.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-weather/+bug/765464      There are some logs, may be it will be helpful for someone who knows what to do with it.

Comment: @jbicha, why did you edit this to take out the suggestion of reporting a bug against the pid?  I may be wrong but I think in that case it can capture more data about the actual live process.

Comment: Because I didn't know that apport could do that but I do now. Thank you!

Comment: Well, thanks for filing, Eugene.  It looks like a real bug.